# Dynamics CRM and ADF pipeline domain

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory

If we have Dynamics CRM in one domain and related Azure data factory pipelines to copy data from or to CRM in another domain so will it  work or affect the pipelines and working?

Answer (score 0):

It will work. You just need to configure your Dynamics CRM linked service correct. And don't worry about whether they are in a same domain or not.

[image]